# Constrained weighted linear regression in R

Tags: r, constraints, linear-regression

I am trying to set up a contrained weighted linear regression. That is to say, that I have a dataset of i observations and three different x values. Each observations has a weight. I want to perform a weighted multiple linear regression using the restrictions that the `weighted mean` of each x value has to be zero and the `weighted standard deviation` should be one.

Since I am new and have no reputation yet, I can‘t post images with latex formulas. So I have to write them down this way.

First restriction `$\sum_{i} w_{i} X_{i,k} = 0$ for k = 1,2,3`.

Second one: `$\sum_{i} w_{i} X_{i,k}^2 = 1$ for k = 1,2,3`.

This is an example dataset:

```
y <- rnorm(10)
w <- rep(0.1, 10)
x1 <- rnorm(10)
x2 <- rnorm(10)
x3 <- rnorm(10)
data <- cbind(y, x1, x2, x3, w)
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = data, weigths = data$w)
```

The weights do not have to be equal for each observation but have to add up to one.
I would like to include these restrictions into the regression. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use the Generalised Linear Model:

```
glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, weights = w, data=data)
```

Data needs to be a data.frame(...).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How does that incorporate the conditions?